# How to remove url protocol from Angular $http get response

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that uses the iframe.ly API to grab the responsive iframe markup from a video on the page the user is currently on. I'm using Angular JS (v1.5.8) to communicate with the API, and to generate a preview of the iframe markup. Everything's working splendidly if the extension is being used on a YouTube page. Here's the basic flow:

**content script** <-- grabs current url

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  theurl: window.location.href 
});
```

**background script** <-- puts current url into url made for the API call:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
       localStorage["theurl"] = request.theurl;
    }
);

var url = "http://iframe.ly/api/iframely?url=" 
+ localStorage["theurl"] + "&api_key=**my api key, to be removed in production**>";
```

**stuff.js** <-- not greatly named, but the Angular bit that makes the call:

```
var iframeApp = angular.module('iframeApp', ['ngSanitize']);

iframeApp.controller('linkCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
     $scope.iframe = data;

      }); 
    });

 iframeApp.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
}]);

    iframeApp.filter('rawHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
}]);
```

**sandboxed.html** <-- again, not greatly named (leftover from when I was trying a different approach for this extension), but the default popup when browser icon is clicked:

```
   <html class="ng-scope" ng-csp ng-app="iframeApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="backgroundscript.js"></script>
  <script src="stuff.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-controller="linkCtrl">
  <h4>Responsive iFrame code is <pre>{{iframe.links.player[0].html}}</pre></h4> 

<div ng-bind-html="iframe.links.player[0].html | rawHtml"></div>
  </body>

</body>

</html>
```

Now! On a YouTube page (for example), this is what happens when the browser icon is clicked:

[image]

Wonderful! BUT! Things get a bit, um, not working at all when I attempt to make the same call when on a Vimeo page. Here's the problem: The source url on the iframe.ly API call to a YouTube page returns a URL that's appended with a https protocol. However, a Vimeo call returns a URL with a non-relative, "//" protocol appended to the source. So, this happens, because obviously this won't work unless you're doing it on an HTML file that's running on a server of some sort, because it otherwise attempts to access a local file:

[image]

Now, I'd like to fix this by calling for the source url (by replacing the `iframe.links.player[0].html` with `iframe.links.player[0].href`) and then putting that inside an iframe inside of a hardcoded responsive div element. That way, my call would return, say `//player.vimeo.com/video/177375994?byline=0&amp;badge=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;title=0`.

So, how could I remove all the protocols from the URLs from the API calls? This would be great, because `player.vimeo.com/video/177375994?byline=0&amp;badge=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;title=0` automatically routes the browser to append the proper protocol, rather than making it think that I'm trying to load a local file, and it does the same when there's no protocol on a YouTube URL, and I'm assuming any other URL for a video as well.

The functionality of the extension is to allow a developer to quickly copy/paste iframe markup, instead of having to type it out, just to make things a tad easier. So, the "//" protocol would actually be fine in the long run if a site is being built, because then it's running on a server, and it doesn't matter. But, for purposes of not looking ugly, it'd be nice if the preview worked for all videos with the extension.

Thank you!

Comment: I added the additional code to the module:
`iframeApp.controller('linkCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
     $scope.iframe = data;
     var newurl = $scope.iframe.links.player[0].href;
     $scope.iframe2 = newurl.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, "");
    
      });

    });`

In sandboxed.html `<div>{{iframe2}}</div>` still gives `//player.vimeo.com/video/136089400?byline=0&badge=0&portrait=0&title=0`. 

But, if I can go from scope---> variable ----> new scope, some regex work must be possible (although it isn't working here, for some reason).

Comment: In other words, I'm wondering if the best avenue might be to store $scope.iframe.links.player[0].href as a variable, then remove the protocol from it at that step, and then declare a new scope for the variable after the protocol has been removed. But I'm missing something, because I'd think the above code would work if this avenue had potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're working on an extension or app with Angular, and you're communicating with public API that you don't have control over, and that API is giving you some guff with some unwanted characters its responses: Never fear!

I successfully pulled the protocol from the get request's returning URL, but after realizing that a URL without a protocol is treated like a local file, too, I added an "http://" protocol to the URL after stripping it. This way, any Vimeo source in the iframe.ly API that had a protocol of "//" would be replaced with an "http://", which ends up redirecting it to an "https://" protocol anyway (it seems safe to put "http://" on anything and have your bases covered, because, at least in Chrome, it'll be sufficient to route to anything SSL protected as well).

So, basically, the problem was that the iframe.ly API was spectacular for finding the source URLs for videos, but the protocols weren't normalized, which caused problems when trying to use those URLs inside of the chrome extension. Here's the code I'm currently using to pull the URLs from the API, and then normalize their protocols to all be "http://":

In the poorly named `stuff.js`, where the Angular code for the extension lives:

```
var iframeApp = angular.module('iframeApp', ['ngSanitize']);

iframeApp.controller('linkCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
     $scope.iframe = data;

     var newurl = $scope.iframe.links.player[0].href;
    var secondurl = newurl.split('/').slice(2).join('/');
    $scope.iframe2 = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl((secondurl.indexOf('://') == -1) ? 'http://' + secondurl : secondurl) ;

     var testurl = $scope.iframe.links.player[0].href;
     $scope.iframe3 = testurl;

     $scope.iframe3 = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(testurl);

      });

    });

 iframeApp.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
}]);

    iframeApp.filter('rawHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
}]);
```

And, in the also-poorly-named sandboxed.html, which is the extension's default popup:

```
<html class="ng-scope" ng-csp ng-app="iframeApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="backgroundscript.js"></script>
  <script src="stuff.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-controller="linkCtrl">
  <h4>Responsive iFrame: <pre><code>&lt;div style=&quot;left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;&quot;&gt;&lt;iframe src=&quot;{{iframe2}}&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;true&quot; webkitallowfullscreen=&quot;true&quot; mozallowfullscreen=&quot;true&quot; style=&quot;top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</code></pre>


<div>Source URL is: <code>{{iframe2}}</code></div>


<div style="left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;"><iframe ng-src="{{iframe2}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe></div>
  </body>


</html>
```

And now, clicking the browser action icon on a Vimeo video's page will not return with the Sad Face graphic that I've come to loathe so, so very much over the past couple weeks:

[image]

And, if I copy/paste that source URL into the browser, we can see that it automatically routes the "http://" protocol to its rightful "https://" protocol:

[image]

And, just for fun, an html page that's populated with stuff copy/pasted from the Responsive iFrame Code section of the default popup:

[image]

Gives us this, when the file is opened locally:

[image]

I have a feeling that any AngularJS purist is looking at this code and shouting "NO NO NO NO NO" at their screen, because, even as a n00b, I'm pretty sure that this Angular code is ugly, and should be separated into different pieces. BUT! It *is* working, and I'd love to hear any suggestions on accomplishing this in a more proper, "Angular Way" :)

Comment: If it's any additional help to somebody: 

I put the [current code on GitHub](https://github.com/sparkholiday/iFramed-d-It-Chrome-Extension) and you can compare it with the [packed version on the Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iframed-it/fajooocnppkgfcogkldkjgamdikhbohk).